# Can't run Linux over Android 4.3 after official update

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, 4.3-jelly-bean, linux

I used to run a Linux (Ubuntu 10.04) on a S3 running android 4.1. I updated the device today with the official rom, android 4.3, then rooted it again. But now I can't run linux anymore.

Any ideias, why this is happening?

Thanks!!

[image: screenshot]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might be a very good idea to reboot your device before continuing troubleshooting this. That /etc/fstab error should not have occurred, so likely there are some strange things hiding out if your RAM right now.